# Break up a string into separate parts

Tags: c, strtok

```
    //PROBLEM NUMBER 2
    //how to store word from pointer2char into wordList array?
```

`New_sentence` is an array holding a string (sentence inputted from user).

`pointers2char` is a pointer array that is supposed to hold pointers to each word of     `New_sentence`.

When function outputs, only the  first word of the string displays, and then program ends.

How do I get all the words from `New_sentence` to be stored in `pointers2char`?

Comment: You are using uninitialized variables `pointers2char[i]` before assign it to the result of strtok().

Comment: How is `pointers2char` declared?

Comment: OK I just need help with one more thing, and that will be all. details in the program. Do I need to use strcpy by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

In your `for`-loop, you start at `i = 1`. Before the first iteration of the loop, `pointers2char[i] != NULL` is evaluated. Since `pointers2char[1]` is most likely uninitialized at this point, it could very well return `NULL`. As a result, you never enter the loop.

Try the following:

```
pointers2char[0] = strtok(New_sentence, " \t");
for (i = 0; pointers2char[i] != NULL; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", pointers2char[i]);
    pointers2char[i + 1] = strok(NULL, " \t");
}
*nWords = i;
```

Comment: i think you're right... when I remove the '!', the second word returns a null. I'm not sure why this happens

Comment: @user2281397 I added a solution suggestion. The `!` is not the problem; the indexing is.

Comment: thank you so much! it returns all the words now. The only problem now is that it gives a warning "assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast" for the line nWords = i;  Is that because nWords is a pointer?

Comment: how do i give you rep btw? I'm new to this site

Comment: @ExP, nWords is a pointer pointed to `int`, and access to `pinters2char[i+1]` may be out of boundary.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your for loop use this.I think it will solve your problem

```
for(i = 0; pointers2char[i] != NULL;)
{
   printf("%s\n", pointers2char[i]);
   nWords++;
   pointers2char[++i] = strtok(NULL, "\t");
}
```

Comment: @user2281397 : use "*nwords = i " instead of nwords = i